# MongoDb agregation vs client side data manipulation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I need to load a certain set of data from MongoDb. Let's assume, that I need to have items list based on certain condition, I need to know items children count, need to include embedded documents that have "moderated = true" and also count all subdocuments with "moderated == false" without including them. Since I have a document with embedded document, I can retrieve all set of data from db and manipulate it on client side with "for". And I also can use

```
db.item.aggregate
```

to create a response with data I need and moreover this response would have the exact needed structure.

The question is what would be a better approach in terms of reducing load on MongoDb:

1. Aggregation with MongoDb?
2. Create needed data on client side?

Comment: Fair enough question in general, but until people can actually see what you are trying to do there really is no definitive answer. The general case which I think is "not an answer" essentially boils down to this, in that "Generally your database server should be a 'higher spec' and therefore have 'more grunt' than your 'client application' machine" and also therefore "There is also the network traffic to consider between 'client and server', which naturally produces and overhead to operations on the 'client'". But that said, you have not represented what you are doing. Please do so.

Answer (score 1):

This is a strange question. Really, if all you care about is reducing the load on MongoDB, then it's better to send yourself the data you need and do the computation on the client. But that defeats some of the purpose of using MongoDB. The real question is, why are you prioritizing reducing the load on MongoDB? Presumably this aggregation is not your main load on the server and you don't want to impact the core operations with this extra aggregation? In that case, a good solution is to add a [hidden secondary](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-hidden-member/) to the replica set (you are running MongoDB in a replica set already, right? ;D) and that hidden secondary's purpose will be to handle data analytics tasks like the aggregation. The data state on the hidden secondary may be slightly behind the data state on the primary, depending on replication lag, but that's generally ok for analytics.